# Rails ActiveRecord change the word used to limit the records returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Rails to access a very old SQL database that uses a non-standard way to limit the number of records returned. Instead of using 'limit' it uses 'rows'. Therefore when I write

```
SomeModel.find(20)
```

ActiveRecord sends "select etc etc limit 1", which blows up. I want to know if I can change the word AR uses from "limit" to "rows"

There's an easy workaround, so I'm not to much bothered, it's just nice to know.

The workaround is;-

```
SomeModel.where(id: 20)[0]
```

If you use '.first' after a 'where' then AREL appends 'limit 1' to the sql so you have to pick out the first entry returned using [0]

Comment: If we are talking about changing the way that the query interface works then there is most likely no simple solution. My guess is that your would have to create your own database adapter or do some insane monkeypatching to get it to work. Migrating the data to a better DB is most likely going to be less work and a better solution.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1143

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the location in the AR query builder where it uses the word 'LIMIT'. Any idea how it can be changed without recoding the AREL for AR?. It doesn't look like there's an option you can parse.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to move to a better database, but in the meantime I have to read and write to the old DB while doing the migration.